# Trouble printing js function result as text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a program that calls and prints a function randomly from an array list. Having trouble making the result print. Here's the code

```
const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".hidden",
  ".demo",
  ".hold",
  ".button",
  "hold"
);
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));

var workouts = [
  "10 push ups",
  "5 pull ups",
  "15 box squats",
  "10 jump squats",
  "8 single leg squats",
  "20 mountain climbers",
  "1 minute plank",
  "20 resistance band pull-aparts",
  "30 second bar hang",
  "15 second hangboard",
  "5 diamond push ups",
  "5 military/wide push ups",
  "15 lunges",
  "1 minute skip rope",
  "30 second wall sit",
];

var workouts = document.getElementById("workouts");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var workouts = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(workouts.length));
  workouts.innerText = workouts[num];
  print(workouts);
});
```

Comment: JavaScript has no function called `print()`. Did you mean to use `console.log()`?

Comment: @MichaelM. - window has a method called print :p ... so `print` === `window.print`

Comment: workouts is a number based on lexical scoping. Rename variable inside listener and it might work without print as well

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, I had no idea, thanks. However, I'm not sure that's what OP meant to write.

Comment: @MichaelM. Mm okay not print or console.log, I suppose it would be to return the value and have the value shown on the html side. So by making the function to make randomly get something from the array list, do I need something extra for it to show when the button is pressed?

Comment: You've redefined `workouts` in your function - use a different variable name as to not overwrite the `var workouts` declared above it. You've actually declared `var workouts` 3 times - change each instance to be unique.

Comment: Even better, swap `var` with `let` since you're already using `const`. These errors will then be flagged with exception of the one declared inside the function, so it's still better practice to make them unique

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're trying to add text to the webpage. I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but this can be done with `document.createElement()` and `document.body.appendChild()`. Like this:

```js
var workouts = [
  "10 push ups",
  "5 pull ups",
  "15 box squats",
  "10 jump squats",
  "8 single leg squats",
  "20 mountain climbers",
  "1 minute plank",
  "20 resistance band pull-aparts",
  "30 second bar hang",
  "15 second hangboard",
  "5 diamond push ups",
  "5 military/wide push ups",
  "15 lunges",
  "1 minute skip rope",
  "30 second wall sit",
];

var workoutBtn = document.getElementById("workouts");
workoutBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var workout = workouts[Math.floor(Math.random() * workouts.length)];
  var el = document.createElement('p');
  el.textContent = workout;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<button id="workouts">Get a workout</button>
```

Your code had a few other problems, but I've fixed them in my code above. The other main issue was that you had multiple variables named `workouts`. I've left the large array named `workouts` and changed the button to `workoutBtn` and the randomly selected workout to simply `workout`.